# Unmarked permutation and combination. Like assigning several elements into several groups as evenly as possible

Tags: algorithm, combinations

Now I have 7 numbers: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. I want to divide them into 3 groups. 
Like  (1,2) (3,4) (5,6,7)
However, the following 4 assignments are the same.

- (1,2) (3,4) (5,6,7)
- (3,4) (1,2) (5,6,7)
- (2,1) (4,3) (6,5,7)
- (7,5,6) (1,2) (4,3)

This one is different from the above 4 assignments.
(1,3) (2,4) (5,6,7)

---

Besides, the number of elements of each group must be as close as possible.
Say 7=2+2+3, it cannot be like 7=1+3+3 or 7=1+2+4. 
I only take 7 numbers and 3 groups as an example, the solution must also applies to different number of numbers and groups, like 9=2+2+2+3.

So

---

1. what kind of problem is my question?
2. how to find out every valid assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's combinatorial enumeration of a class of partitions. My strategy is to loop over all two-part partitions into (things in a part of size q) and (things in a part of size q + 1) and then all even partitions within those parts.

```
import itertools


def partition_by_index(lst, indexes):
  lsts = ([], [])
  indicator = [False] * len(lst)
  for i in indexes:
    indicator[i] = True
  for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    lsts[indicator[i]].append(x)
  return lsts


def enumerate_even_partitions(lst, k):
  n = len(lst)
  if n == 0:
    yield ((),) * k
    return
  q, r = divmod(n, k)
  assert r == 0
  for indexes in itertools.combinations(range(1, n), n - q):
    lst0, lst1 = partition_by_index(lst, indexes)
    for subpartition in enumerate_even_partitions(lst1, k - 1):
      yield (tuple(lst0),) + subpartition


def enumerate_maximally_even_partitions(lst, k):
  n = len(lst)
  q, r = divmod(n, k)
  # k - r parts of size q and r parts of size q + 1
  for indexes in itertools.combinations(range(n), r * (q + 1)):
    lst0, lst1 = partition_by_index(lst, indexes)
    for subpartition0 in enumerate_even_partitions(lst0, k - r):
      for subpartition1 in enumerate_even_partitions(lst1, r):
        yield subpartition0 + subpartition1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't get your point and I cannot read the code you wrote. So can you explain it and write the code in C#?